# Regex for not containing consecutive characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't figure out javascript regex that would satisfy all those requirements:

**The string can only contain underscores and alphanumeric characters. 
It must begin with a letter, not include spaces, not end with an underscore, and not contain two consecutive underscores.**

This is as far as I came, but 'not containing consecutive underscores' part is the hardest to add.

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]+[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

Comment: Please tell me this is not a password format requirement.

Comment: Perhaps, you might write it as `/^[A-Z](?!.*__)(?:\w*[A-Z0-9])?$/i`

Comment: If this is targetting passwords, please refer to [Reference - Password Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345922/reference-password-validation/)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use multiple lookaheads (neg. ones in this case):

```
^(?!.*__)(?!.*_$)[A-Za-z]\w*$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/CMgEVb/3/).

---

Broken down this says:

```
^           # start of the line
(?!.*__)    # neg. lookahead, no two consecutive underscores (edit 5/31/20: removed extra Kleene star)
(?!.*_$)    # not an underscore right at the end
[A-Za-z]\w* # letter, followed by 0+ alphanumeric characters
$           # the end
```

---

As `JavaScript` snippet:

```js
let strings = ['somestring', '_not_this_one', 'thisone_', 'neither this one', 'but_this_one', 'this__one_not', 'this_one__yes']

var re = /^(?!.*__)(?!.*_$)[A-Za-z]\w*$/;
strings.forEach(function(string) {
    console.log(re.test(string));
});
```

Please do not restrain passwords!

Comment: Why the `\n` ??

Comment: Looks awesome. One error tho: 'this_one__yes' <- this shouldn't match because it contains 2 consecutive underscores

Answer (score 5):

You can also use

```
^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9]|(_(?!_)))+[a-zA-Z0-9]$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QgbEYV/1/)

The only change comparing to your regex is changing `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` to `[a-zA-Z0-9]|(_(?!_))`. I removed underscore from the character set and allow it in the second part of the alternative if it's not followed by another one.

`(?!_)` is negative lookahead meaning that `_` cannot be next character

Comment: Does not work with `a` or `b` or `ab`, see https://regex101.com/r/QgbEYV/2 (meaning the string must be at least 3 characters long, dunno if this is a requirement or not).

Answer (score 1):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/CMgEVb/4)

```
^[a-z](?!\w*__)(?:\w*[^\W_])?$
```

- `^` Assert position as the start of the line
- `[a-z]` Match any lowercase ASCII letter. The code below adds the `i` (case-insensitive) flag, thus this also matches the uppercase variables
- `(?!\w*__)` Negative lookahead ensuring two underscores do not exist in the string
- `(?:\w*[^\W_])?` Optionally match the following

  - `\w*` Match any number of word characters
  - `[^\W_]` Match any word character except `_`. Explained: Match anything that is <strike>not not</strike> a word character, but not `_` (since it's in the negated set).
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line

```js
let a = ['somestring', '_not_this_one', 'thisone_', 'neither this one', 'but_this_one', 'this__one_not', 'this_one__yes']
var r = /^[a-z](?!\w*__)(?:\w*[^\W_])?$/i

a.forEach(function(s) {
    if(r.test(s)) console.log(s)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler version, without lookaround (so also usable with regex flavours that don't support them such as POSIX ERE, or even `sed`-style regex with simple alterations):

```
^[a-zA-Z](_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```